# Filter by condtion Master Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a code that merges different g sheet files together into a master spreadsheet from a given folder. Now I'd like to create a filter in the code which filters column 71 (BT) for only criteria "ABC" and merges the data into one. Would you guys help a brother out?

```
     function myFunction() {

     var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id");

     var filesInterator = folder.getFiles();


     var file;
     var fileType;
     var ssID;
     var combinedData = [];
     var data;


     while(filesInterator.hasNext()){
     file = filesInterator.next();
    fileType = file.getMimeType();
    if(fileType === "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"){
    ssID = file.getId();
    data = getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID);
    combinedData = combinedData.concat(data);

    } // if ends here
    }  // while loops ends here

    //Logger.log(combinedData.length);

    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("QwERTY");
    ws.getRange("A2:BK").clearContent();
    ws.getRange(2,1,combinedData.length,combinedData[0].length).setValues(combinedData);

    }

    function getDataFromSpreadsheet(ssID) {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("XYZ");
    var data = ws.getRange("A2:KB" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(r => r[0] != '');

    return data;

    }
```

Comment: @MetaMan , you were so helpful with my last post, perhaps this time you would also know how to make a few adjustments to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines of code:

```
let filterCriteria = SpreadsheetApp
    .newFilterCriteria()
    .whenTextContains("ABC")
    .build();
let filter = ws.getRange(1, 71).createFilter();
filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(71, filterCriteria).sort(71, true);
```

Assuming, that `ws` is your working sheet and the criteria you're looking for is `when text contains "ABC"`, then the snippet above will create a filter on the `ws` sheet on  the `BT1` cell.

However, please bear in mind that depending on the exact criteria of your filter you can modify the current one by taking a look at the methods available for the `FilterCriteriaBuilder` Class [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script FilterCriteriaBuilder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria-builder);
- [Apps Script Filter Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter);
- [Apps Script FilterCriteria Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter-criteria).

Comment: thank you very much for helping me to solve this issue, you really made my day!

Comment: one question though if you don't mind, would you happen to know how to modify the above code, so that before merging spreadsheets from the folder into a master sheet, checks against criterion in column 71 (tekst "ABC"), and then marges files together only for the relevant rows.